# Android Segmented Controller

Tags: android, github

I am using a Segmented Android Controller from Github and they specify that I need to add these folders to my android project but I'm not sure exactly sure what they are saying. I am new. It would help greatly if someone could help clarify what they want me to do in the activity I want to implement this in and the xml file/res folder. Thank you. Here is the link: https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control and specificly the section I'm having trouble with.-
Copy(or merge) below files into corresponding file/folder:

```
SegmentedGroup.java
res/drawable/*
res/drawable-v14/*
res/values/colors.xml
res/values/dimens.xml
res/values/styles.xml (only RadioButton style) (This is not code, but it didn't let me post the question)
```

Comment: You don't need to do any of that if you use the Gradle dependency

Comment: Are you using Android developer studio?

Comment: Yes I'm using Android Studio!

Comment: @cricket_007 on the github tutorial at the bottom it states SegmentedGroup segmented2 = (SegmentedGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.segmented2);
segmented2.setTintColor(Color.DKGRAY); but I'm getting an error on "rootView" I know it's the parent layout but I don't know what to do with the information.

Comment: That should be if you are using a Fragment and you've named the layout you inflated rootView... That's not a problem with the library

Comment: For example, see the nested Fragment class where that code sample comes from. https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/info/hoang8f/mymo/segmented/demo/SampleActivity.java